# How can I make sense of alpha values obtained from scikit-learn OC-SVM?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, libsvm, one-class

I am building a ML model that uses the OC-SVM for anomaly detection. For our cost function we require the alphas obtained from the OC-SVM. We use the OC-SVM of scikit-learn, which I assume is based on libsvm (as it is stated that this is the case for sklearn.svm.SVC).

Now to obtain the alphas, I followed the suggestion given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860938/how-to-get-all-alpha-values-of-scikit-learn-svm-classifier assuming the same method works for the OC-SVM case.
However, I notice there seems to be a discrepancy between alpha values obtained here and what is described in the dual problem of the OC-SVM. In the dual problem (also described in the libsvm manual [https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) page 5) it is required for alpha values to sum to 1. Using the method above, we obtain many alpha values of exactly 1. Therefore, summing them would give a much larger value than 1.

I was wondering, how is the dual problem implemented in the scikit-learn OC-SVM through libsvm? Is this requirement to the alpha values actually present? Is there a better way to obtain them, or can I simply divide the svm.dual_coef_ by the sum of its values?

Comment: LIBSVM is actually solving a scaled version of the objective (Eq. 8, top of pg. 6 on the LIBSVM document you linked), so the constraint is slightly different (you're talking about Eq. 7): the $\alpha_i$s sum to $\nu l$, which is the same $\nu$ that sklearn uses for OneClassSVM (default 0.5), and $l$ is the number of training data points. Is that consistent with what happens when you sum up the $\alpha$ values?

Comment: So if you *really* need the $\alpha_i$ values with the sum-to-one constraint, it looks like you can divide the $\alpha_i$ values that you get here by $\nu l$, which you have.

Comment: Hi tchainzzz, yes I now see the difference between Eq. 8 and Eq. 7. I checked and it is indeed correct, the sum of the alphas is equal to . It would be the same as doing: alphas = alphas / sum(alphas), but to stick closer to the dual problems I will implement dividing by . 
Thank you for clearing that up! Now I know that the models were implemented correctly. It makes sense since  can sort of be seen as the fraction of anomalies, right? And the nr. of s scales with the number of datapoints you have of course.

Comment: Of course! But I'm not sure that's the right interpretation of $\nu$; it's a *bound,* not a constant quantity, that allows for some misclassification. It lower-bounds the # of support vectors (or points "close" to the decision boundary; i.e. # of nonzero $\alpha_i$s), while upper-bounding the proportion of training errors. I don't think I understand the details of why that is, but the LIBSVM document does cite the original source.

Comment: That is an interesting thing to consider. I think a better way of phrasing what I meant to say is:   regulates the amount of support vectors chosen by the OC-SVM through its decision boundary and the value of    is related to the fraction of anomalous data points the OC-SVM aims for. When I play around with it,  a    of 0.1 will result in roughly 10% anomalous datapoints in validation, while a   of 0.9 will result in roughly 90% anomalous datapoints. Since   is bound to (0, 1] it corresponds well to these fractions of anomalous data. But it might be a good study    a bit more.